# How to assign indexes to Windows Forms controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a desktop application in C # Winforms. In my application, I need to assign an index to each control to identify it.

I explain, when the user passes the mouse pointer over a control, it changes color, by removing the pointer or clicking on the control, it returns to its original color and remains "selected", but, when selected, the control should NOT change its color when positioning the pointer over it.

Well, I need to know which control is selected at the moment since not only the user can select it, but also my application can select controls automatically.

So it occurred to me to assign a numeric value to each control to see if it is selected, that is:

```
Control controla = new Control();
Panel controlb = new Panel();

if(SelectedOption == controla.GetControlIndex())
{
   //controla is the selected option
}
```

Creating an extension method (I wanted to create an extension property, but as far as it is not possible):

```
public static class Ext
{
    private static int _ControlIndex = -1;

    public static void SetControlIndex(this Control control, int index) => _ControlIndex = index;

    public static int GetControlIndex(this Control control) => _ControlIndex;
}
```

I did it in this way thinking that `controla` is an object and `controlb` is another, then the extension method should be different for each one, but not, if I assign a zero as an index to `controla`, and then assign the index one to `controlb`, then the index for both is one.

What I want is to be able to assign an index to each control as if it were a kind of unique identifier.

**NOTE**: I already know the `TabIndex` property, the `SetChildIndex()` and `GetChildIndex()` methods, those do not work for what I want.

Comment: Control.Tag Property.

Comment: When you need a unique control identifier, why not using the `Control.Handle` property?

Comment: @KBO `Control.Handle` gets the pointer identifier of the control, I do not think it's a good idea to manipulate it for something as simple as this, `Control.Tag` is better

Comment: @Hector: The window handle is read-only and unique by default (HWND), you cannot manipulate/change it accidentially. Every native MFC program uses handles like HWND continously. So, from my point of view, it is not required to introduce another kind of uniqueness.